# How can encode array of CGPoint in Swift

Tags: swift, codable, cgpoint

Hello I found nice solution without array from  [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/best-approach-for-codable-on-types-i-dont-own/28915/4) works OK

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EncodablePoint: Encodable {
    var wrappedValue: CGPoint
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case x
        case y
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var c = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try c.encode(wrappedValue.x, forKey: .x)
        try c.encode(wrappedValue.y, forKey: .y)
    }
}
//usage:
struct Foo: Encodable {
    @EncodablePoint var pt: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 123, y: 456)
    var other = "zxcv"
}

let foo = Foo()
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(foo)
print(String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil") // {"pt":{"x":123,"y":456},"other":"zxcv"}
```

Please I would like the similar solution with array, If anybody know please help me.
I would like somethlig like:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EncodablePointsArray: Encodable {
    var wrappedValue: [CGPoint]
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        ?????
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        ??????
    }
}


struct Foo2: Encodable {
    @EncodablePointsArray var pt: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint]
    var other = "zxcv"
}

let foo2 = Foo2()
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(foo2)
print(String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")
// I wold like output like : {"ArrayPoints“:[{„x“:1.1,“y“:1.2},{„x“:2.1,“y“:3.4}]},"other":"zxcv"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going off of antiquated information. `[CGPoint]` is `Codable` without any extensions now.

```swift
struct Foo2: Encodable {
  var pt: [CGPoint] = []
  var other = "zxcv"
}
```

If you actually need a wrapper, please post the code that requires it. Your question suggests that you don't need a wrapper.

Comment: Although this is true, it's not what OP asks for. Encoding `Foo2` will have as result this `{"pt":[[1.1,1.2],[2.1,3.4]],"other":"zxcv"}`. Clearly OP asks for something like this `{"pt":[{"x":1.1,"y":1.2},{"x":2.1,"y":3.4}]},"other":"zxcv"}`

Answer (score 1):

Using [unkeyedContainer()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/2893802-unkeyedcontainer) and [nestedContainer(keyedBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2893204-nestedcontainer) functions will do the trick:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EncodablePointsArray: Encodable {
    var wrappedValue: [CGPoint]
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case x
        case y
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var unkeyedContainer = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try wrappedValue.forEach {
            var container = unkeyedContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            try container.encode($0.x, forKey: .x)
            try container.encode($0.y, forKey: .y)
        }
    }
}
```

Using you example:

```
struct Foo2: Encodable {
    @EncodablePointsArray var pt: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 1.1, y: 1.2), CGPoint(x: 2.1, y: 3.4)]
    var other = "zxcv"
}

let foo2 = Foo2()
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(foo2)
    print(String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will have as a result this:

```
{
    "pt": [
        {
            "x": 1.1000000000000001,
            "y": 1.2
        },
        {
            "x": 2.1000000000000001,
            "y": 3.3999999999999999
        }
    ],
    "other": "zxcv"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`EncodablePoint` acts here like a wrapper for `CGPoint`, so from the client perspective `EncodablePoint` is a new type with `CGPoint` property.

If used as a property wrapper, it acts like array of `CGPoint`. But after encoding it turns it into a custom object with `x` and `y` coordinates.

Based on the results you want to achieve after decoding such an object, there are two options here.

#### Encoding array of `EncodablePoint`

Let's build property wrapper like this

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EncodablePointArray: Encodable {
    var wrappedValue: [EncodablePoint]
}
```

Then client of the wrapper should create instances of `EncodablePoint`

```
struct Points: Encodable {
    @EncodablePointArray var pt: [EncodablePoint] = [
        EncodablePoint(wrappedValue: CGPoint(x: 123, y: 456)),
        EncodablePoint(wrappedValue: CGPoint(x: 789, y: 123)),
        EncodablePoint(wrappedValue: CGPoint(x: 456, y: 789))
    ]
    var other = "zxcv"
}
```

Decoding that will give you results you wanted

```
{"pt":{"values":[{"x":123,"y":456},{"x":789,"y":123},{"x":456,"y":789}]},"other":"zxcv"}
```

But I think you want to use array of `CGPoint`, so...

#### Encoding array of `CGPoint`

If you want to use `CGPoint`s directly like this

```
struct Points: Encodable {
    @EncodablePointArray var pt: [CGPoint] = [
        CGPoint(x: 123, y: 456),
        CGPoint(x: 789, y: 123),
        CGPoint(x: 456, y: 789)
    ]
    var other = "zxcv"
}
```

You have to build your wrapper with `CGPoint`s

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EncodablePointArray: Encodable {
    var wrappedValue: [CGPoint]
}
```

But the decoded String will be different:

```
{"pt":{"values":[[123,456],[789,123],[456,789]]},"other":"zxcv"}
```